# CHILKAT CRYPT failed in 64 bit machine

Tags: asp.net, cryptography, iis-6, encryption

I have a 64 bit CHILKAT CRYPT assembly (for .NET 4.0). when I run my application in IIS 6.0 in Windows Server 2003 (64 bit) I got an error that the assembly is not found. on the other hand, in my local machine I have a 32 bit assembly and Windows7 32 bit and it works fine.

What should I do to to overcome this error and what are the causes?

Answer (score 3):

The main problem I found is that the web application is built for platform x86 and deployed to x64 machine on which the machine does not allow 32 bit programs to run.
in this case the error that indicates that the assembly is not found is not correct. its simply not compatible with x64 machine.

I found that the following steps solved the problem:

1. Add the 64 bit assembly to web application project (visual studio 2010)
2. Select x64 for target platform from the configuration manager in visual studio
3. Build the solution and deploy it

This steps really fixed my problem.

Comment: Thanks for reporting back Ashraf, you may accept your own answer after a while.